# 360 stereo panorama viewer with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, stereo-3d, panoramas, 360-panorama-viewer, 360-panorama

I have two panoramic images that I have stitched together using some proprietary software and my stereo camera. I would like to visualise them in VR mode inside my app.

Is there any tutorial for realising this using Unity?

Comment: is it a spherical panorama or just a 360 horizon? I don't know any tutorials on this though.

Comment: Did you tried this asset ?https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/38755

Comment: @Nika: it's a Spherical panorama

Comment: @DoughnutZombie: "This package includes only the script for capturing 360° panoramas. It does not include any scenes, models, textures, etc." I think this script produces just the images, but I need a tutorial for creating the viewer

Comment: i've once tested just converting 360 image to cube faces, and using as skybox (6 sided).. For example pano2vr can convert to that, probably other tools also.